# Subtract Time from CSV using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv, time

Hi I would like to subtract time from a CSV array using Ruby

> time[0] is 12:12:00AM
>   time[1] is 12:12:01AM

Here is my code

```
time_converted = DateTime.parse(time)
difference = time_converted[1].to_i - time_converted[0].to_i
p difference
```

However, I got 0

`p time[0].to_i` gives me 12

is there a way to fix this?

Comment: FYI: [When should you use `DateTime` and when should you use `Time`?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#class-DateTime-label-When+should+you+use+DateTime+and+when+should+you+use+Time-3F)

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: What would you like to get as an outcome? difference in seconds? minutes or what?

Comment: @marmeladze difference in seconds. The purpose I had in mind was to form a nested array here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48919172/counting-transitions-in-nested-array-using-ruby

Comment: `Time.parse(t2) - Time.parse(t1)` will possibly work you. It will give difference as a float number - where you can easily can parse it to integer. [a more compact solution here](https://repl.it/@marmeladze1/MushyDeterminedCharactermapping)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Time#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime) to define the format of the parsed string.

In your case the string is `%I:%M:%S%p`.

- `%I` = 12 hour time
- `%M` = minutes
- `%S` = seconds
- `%p` = AM/PM indicator

So to parse your example:

```
require 'time'
time = %w(12:12:00AM 12:12:01AM)
parsed_time = time.map { |t| Time.strptime(t, '%I:%M:%S%p').to_i }
parsed_time.last - parsed_time.first

=> 1
```

Comment: I got an error saying undefined method for 'strptime'. Is there anything missing?

Comment: @JoshuaNg You have to `require 'time'`

Comment: ah. fixed that.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Ruby [DateTime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) class and parse your dates into objects of that class.

Comment: Since the DateTime object takes one string at a time to parse you may want to try something like:

   time_converted = time.map() { |t| DateTime.new(t.to_s) }

Comment: p time_converted[0] gives me `#<DateTime: 0012-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((1725441j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>`  Is there a way to get only time?

Comment: Ultimately, the goal is to subtract time_converted[1] with time_converted[0]

Comment: The DateTime class has a `to_time` method that will return a `Time` object. Try that.

Comment: From the docs, "if you need to deal with dates and times in a historical context you’ll want to use DateTime". For regular time parsing you should use `Time`